# No llega el objeto del controlador a mi vista

Tags: php, sql, poo

estoy teniendo un problema y es el siguiente:
Desde mi modelo productos hago una funcion para que me saque X productos random

```
public function getRandom($limit)
{
    $productos = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $limit");
    return $productos;
}
```

Hago la instancia de la clase en mi controllador:

```
public function index()
{
    $producto = new Producto();
    $productos = $producto->getRandom(3);
    // var_dump($productos->fetch_object());
    require_once 'views/producto/destacados.php';
}
```

Hasta aqui todo bien ya que el var_dump si me regresa un objeto, el problema viene en mi vista destacados.php ya que parece no estar llegando a esta por que me dice undefined variable productos, mi vista es asi:

```
<div id="content" class="container row">
<h1 class="col-12">Algunos de nuestros productos</h1>
<hr width="75%" />

<?php while ($prod = $productos->fetch_object()) : ?>
    <div class="product col-4">
        <img src="<?= base_url ?>uploads/img<?= $prod->img ?>" class="foto_edit">
        <h2><?= $prod->nombre ?></h2>
        <p><?= $prod->precio ?>€</p>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-compra">Comprar</a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Lo raro es que tengo otras vistas como Crear productos o Editar productos y todo llega correctamente teniendo una estructura igual.

Comment: Creo que te falta hacer un `return` de `$productos` en el controlador.

Comment: Mmmm el return lo tengo en el modelo y en el controllador si me llega el objeto, el problema es que no llega del controllador a la vista, igualmente probé el return y tampoco funciona. Gracias de todas formas!

Comment: Parece que estás usando codeigniter, no?

Comment: No, estoy con php a pelo

Comment: No tendras algun otro require_once de esa misma vista en el controlador? Ya que al usar el require_once solo lo va a incluir una vez. prueba solo con `require`

Comment: Gracias parece que era eso porque funciono bien, igualmente en mi controlador solo tengo una función que me muestra el destacados.php pero si uso otros require_once en otras funciones pero que muestran vistas diferentes, por eso me parece raro... Igualmente me ha funcionado asiq muchas gracias!